# Porque se produce error JSP webapp Azure

Tags: java, jsp, azure

Cordial saludo

Buenas noches

termine un proyecto y lo acabo de subir en azure tengo la conexion con sql server azure, lo probé desde local y la conexion y funciona perfectamente pero cuando esta en azure me mande el siguiente error:

[image: el codigo del controlador es el siguiente]

El código es:

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String accion=request.getParameter("accion");
            if(accion.equals("ingresar"))
            {
            
            String usuario =request.getParameter("email");
            //String nombrecompleto =request.getParameter(dao.getUsuarios("name"));
            String pass = request.getParameter("password");
           
            user.setCorreo(usuario);
            
            
            user.setPassword(pass);
            r=dao.validarUsuario(user);
            if(r==1){
                  HttpSession usua =request.getSession(true);
                  usua.setAttribute("usuario",usuario);
                  //usua.setMaxInactiveInterval(600);
                   //response.sendRedirect("administrador/index.jsp");
                 //request.getSession().setAttribute("nom", nombrecompleto);
                 //request.getSession().setAttribute("usuario",usuario);
                
                request.getRequestDispatcher("administrador/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }else{
                 response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?accion=usuario&claveincorrecta");
                 //out.println("<div class='text-danger text-center'>Usuario y/o Clave incorrecta!</div>");
                //request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            
            }else{
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                 //request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
      
    }
```

y el codigo de usuarioDao es el siguiente en local funciona la aplicacion pero en la nube me envie el error comentado si pueden colaborar.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

El codigo de usuarioDao es el siguiente

> public int  validarUsuario(Usuarios users) {
> int r=0;
> String sql="select * from usuarios where Mail_users=? and Pass_users=?";
> try
> {
> conn=cn.getConexion();
> ps =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
>
> ```
>        ps.setString(1, users.correo);
>        ps.setString(2, users.password);
>        
>        rs=ps.executeQuery();
>        while(rs.next()){
>            r=r+1;
>            users.setCorreo(rs.getString("Mail_users"));
>            users.setPassword(rs.getString("Pass_users"));
>            users.setPerfil(rs.getInt("Type_users"));
>           
>            
>        }
>        if(r==1)
>        {
>            return 1;
>        }else{
>            return 0;
>        }
>    }catch(SQLException e){return 0;}
> }
> ```

la imagen de funcionamiento local

Comment: Pues, amigo, estás haciendo `user.setCorreo(usuario);` y `user.setPassword(pass);` pero no veo dónde instancias `user`. El error te está diciendo que le estás mandando un objeto que apunta a null y tampoco vemos cómo te funciona eso localmente.

Comment: Revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados/42978?r=SearchResults&s=2|0.0000#42978